# Run Screen process with ProcessBuilder "

Tags: java, processbuilder

I want to start an Screen process in a directory:

```
ProcessBuilder bu = new ProcessBuilder( "screen -h 5000 -dmS BF1 java -Xmx1024M -jar spigot.jar -p 20000" );
bu.directory(new File("/home/cloud/bedfight/BF1"));
bu.start();
```

But it got this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "screen -h 5000 -dmS BF1 java -Xmx1024M -jar spigot.jar -p 20000" (in directory "/home/cloud/bedfight/BF1"): error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
        at hydoria.cloud.Main$1.run(Main.java:126)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:187)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
        ... 3 more
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at the error message: `...No such file or directory`

Comment: Are you aware of how a command line is built? If you are, you know where your error comes from. Hint: `man execve`

Comment: @Zyn This directory exists!

Comment: Is `/home/cloud/bedfight/BF1/screen` also exists?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html